# jQuery autocomplete not displaying text values but populates elements

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I have a jQuery autocomplete that is functioning properly, except it is improperly displaying text values returned in the function.  My backend is ColdFusion.

Backend Function (in a CFC):

```
<cffunction name="companyNameList" access="remote" output="false" hint="I return a list of companies with IDs" returnformat="JSON">
    <cfargument name="searchterm" required="false" default="" />

    <cfset var returnArray = arrayNew(1) />

    <cfquery name="companyNameList" datasource="#request.dsn#">
        SELECT companyID, companyName
        FROM tbl_companies
        WHERE companyName LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#arguments.searchterm#%" />
    </cfquery>

    <cfloop query="companyNameList">
        <cfset companyStruct = structNew() />
        <cfset companyStruct['value'] = companyID />
        <cfset companyStruct['label'] = companyName />

        <cfset arrayAppend(returnArray,companyStruct) />
    </cfloop>

    <cfreturn returnArray />
</cffunction>
```

My jQuery javascript (it's wrapped in cfoutput tags, necessitating a second hash mark as an escape value):

```
        $(function() {             
        $("##defaultcompanyname").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "secure/cfc/ajax.cfc?method=companyNameList",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        searchterm: request.term
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        response(data);
                    }
                })
            },
            minLength: 3,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('##defaultcompanyid').val(ui.item.value);
                $('##defaultcompanyname').val(ui.item.label);
            }
        });
    });
```

And the relevant form block:

```
        <p class="ui-widget">
            <label for="defaultcompanyname">Default Company Association</label>
            <cfinput type="text" size="30em;" name="defaultcompanyname" id="defaultcompanyname" value="" />
            <cfinput type="hidden" name="defaultcompanyid" id="defaultcompanyid" value="0" />
        </p>
```

When I use type in 'test' as my test value, this is the returned JSON:

```
[{"value":2,"label":"Test Company"},{"value":3,"label":"2nd Test Company"}]
```

The list is populating, but it populates with empty strings.  If I select one, the hidden  defaultcompanyid value does populate a number, but the defaultcompanyname value empties my text.  What am I missing?

EDIT: Updated question with new information based on responses that partially resolved original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to adjust your JSON.
jQueryUI expects the data to be fomatted like

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "label": "Test Company"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "label": "2nd Test Company"
    }
]
```

Then change your `select()` method:

```
select: function (event, ui) {
        $('#defaultcompanyid').val(ui.item.id);
        $('#defaultcompanyname').val(ui.item.label);
    }
```

If you can't alter the JSON, try to manipulate the `_renderItem()` method, have a look at the [example source code in the docs](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data).

Edit: Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V4zvZ/1/)

Comment: I've added a fiddle link, please have a look at it

Comment: @Thorsten The double ## is because his code is inside an cfoutput and coldfusion uses the pound sign in evaluation, make sure you read the whole question

Comment: I had to leave this problem and move on to other things, but I've been able to come back to it with fresh eyes and noticed I failed to update my code correctly.  Your solution solved the problem entirely.  Thank you for your help.