# jquery ui autocomplete no data returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I'm having trouble with autocomplete.  I have the following code;

```
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

$(function() {
    $('.namesuggestclass').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'cfc/basic.cfc?method=getIndivs',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    searchterm: request.term
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                },
                success: function(data){
                    response(data);
                }
            })
        },
        minLength: 3,
        onSearchError: function (query, jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            alert(ui.item.ISRECNUM);
        }
    });
});



<cfinput name="namesuggest" class="namesuggestclass">
```

I'm running on a Coldfusion 10 server.  When I type in 3 or more characters I get 3 blank lines.

My cfc is:

```
<cffunction name="getIndivs" access="remote" HINT="Get All Resources" returnformat="json" output="false" >
        <cfargument name="searchterm" required="True" default="">
        <cfset local.returnArray =ArrayNew(1)>
        <cfquery name="local.get_Indivs" datasource="#request.dsn#" maxrows=20>
            SELECT ui.id as isrecnum, UI.lastname + ', ' + UI.firstname as iname , c.name as companyname, c.city as companycity, UI.Status_Flag
            FROM users_info AS UI left join
            companies as c on c.id = ui.current_company_number
            WHERE 0=0
            And ui.status_Flag != 'D'
            <cfif trim(arguments.searchterm) NEQ "">
                AND UI.lastname + ' ' + ui.firstname + ' ' + c.name like
                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#left(trim(arguments.searchterm),255)#%">
            <cfelse>
              AND UI.lastname = 'abcdefg'  <!--- return empty query   vjl  2011/07/27 --->
            </cfif>
            ORDER BY lastname, firstname
        </cfquery>
        <cfloop query="local.get_Indivs">
            <cfset indivStruct = structNew() />
            <cfset indivStruct['ISRECNUM'] = ISRECNUM />
            <cfset indivStruct['INAME'] = INAME />
            <cfset indivStruct['COMPANYNAME'] = COMPANYNAME />
            <cfset indivStruct['COMPANYCITY'] = COMPANYCITY />
            <cfset arrayAppend(local.returnArray,indivStruct) />
        </cfloop>
        <CFRETURN local.returnArray>
    <!--- <CFRETURN local.get_Indivs> --->
    </cffunction>
```

The data returned from the cfc call is;
[{"ISRECNUM":77137,"INAME":"Lan, Donald","COMPANYNAME":"Company A","COMPANYCITY":"Dallas"},{"ISRECNUM":240316,"INAME":"Lan, Mike","COMPANYNAME":"Company B","COMPANYCITY":"Calgary"},
etc..............]

EDIT:  I updated my code and data. I can't see what I'm doing so different from working examples.

Comment: So, uhm... What's the syntax error? where is it?

Comment: Sorry, just edited the title.

Comment: your keys in json seem to be uppercase, and javascript is case sensitive. Could that be why?

Comment: @user990016 - Did you search the archives first? The problem is your function is returning the JSON in a totally different format than the plugin is expects (and key names are case sensitive as KevinB mentioned).  There are a bunch of threads on using autocomplete, [this one for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737509/jquery-autocomplete-not-displaying-text-values-but-populates-elements) . Also, see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553467/populate-select-list-with-ajax/25576481#25576481) for a description of the format returned by CF. Voting to close.

Comment: My guess is that you are simply returning the ColdFusion query object as JSON rather than in a format that is expected by jQuery UI.

Comment: Leigh:  Yes, I searched quite a bit.  But I've been testing quite a few autosuggest versions I think I'm confusing myself.  I think Scott might be on to something.  Thank you Kevin for pointing out the case problem.  But I don't see how it mattered with the code so far.

Comment: Scott and I are saying the same thing ;-) Look at the links above. The second link explains how your query data is being formatted now (incorrect). The first link shows how to produce the format the plugin expects.  Also, since you are using jQuery, you do not need `<cfinput>`. Just use a standard html `<input>` field.

Comment: Data now is;  [{"ISRECNUM":77137,"INAME":"Lan, Donald","COMPANYNAME":"Company A, P.C.","COMPANYCITY":"Dallas"},{"ISRECNUM":240316,"INAME":"Lan, Mike","COMPANYNAME":"Company B","COMPANYCITY":"Calgary"},  etc.....];

Comment: Still getting blank results.

Comment: That still does not match the [default formats supported by the plugin](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/): array of strings, or an array of objects with `label` and `value` properties.  Your structure keys are still in upper case and are not named "label" and "value" (case sensitive!).  Either a) change your CF code to return those keys instead  OR b) change the `select()` function code to use whatever keys you are returning (see first thread).  The code you posted is not doing anything other than generating an alert.

Comment: I wish it was giving me an alert.  I modified the original code above.  Still only blank lines ( strangely enough the correct number of blank lines according to what is returned by the cfc) show up under the autocomplete input element.

Comment: It's working now.  I had to go to the value/label data model. But when I select from the list,  item.value is placed in the input field.  Is there a way to put item.label in the input field.  It's not a big deal,  but the user would like it better. I guess I could just switch the elements when creating the json data.

Comment: (Edit) Unless there is a specific reason you need to do otherwise, it is simpler to stick with the default "label/value" keys.  *Is there a way to put item.label in the input field.* You can change the `select` function to do whatever you want. See how [this static example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) assigns the "label" to a text field  and the "value" to a hidden field?

Answer (score 1):

As vilsad said: the json data format is wrong. You try to rebuild the datas that got from database, the json format needed by jqueryui-autocomplete is:

```
label:xxxx  --display as select's title 
value:xxxx  --as select element's value
```

In php ,I format my data like this:

```
$ds=$db->query('select id,title from products whrere title like'.keyword.'%');
$result=array(
    'label'=>$ds['title'],
    'value'=>$ds['id']
);
echo json_encode($result);
```

forgive my english

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your json objects are not as expected by the autocomplete plugin, either correct it inside your server side code or use autocomplete plugins _renderItem to make the changes in client side.

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem